# android : isDirectory() function always returns false

Tags: java, android, directory, android-arrayadapter, listactivity

The **isDirectory()** function returns false even though the Arraylist contains the path.

The Item of an Arraylist has the path to the internal storage and the SD Card.
Would any one give any solution for this.

Here is the code -

```
public class FileBrowser extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<String> listItems;
String ROOT_PATH1 = "/storage/emulated/0";
String ROOT_PATH2 = "/storage/sdcard1";
String parent="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_browser);
    setRoot();
}

private void setRoot() {
    listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    listItems.add("<-BACK");
    listItems.add(ROOT_PATH1);
    listItems.add(ROOT_PATH2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.file_list_row, listItems);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}

//on clicking any item in the dialog
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

     int selectedRow = (int)id;
     int y=0;

     if(selectedRow == 0){
          setRoot();
     }else
     {
          File file = new File(listItems.get(selectedRow));
          if(file.isDirectory()){
              getFiles(file.listFiles());
              //opening  pdf files
          }else{
             //neither pdf file nor directory
          }

     }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you're listing the wrong directory? Try to output the "file" and compare it with our fs whether it really exists.

Comment: Yes,it does.Since a few days back this code was working fine.

Comment: Maybe the mounting of your SD Card is wrong. Try Files.exists() as well

Comment: The problem exists with the internal storage as well.

Comment: Yes I debugged the code.

Comment: @TeeKay nobody can run your code. You debugged it, then did you look at the `file` variable and checked its value? What about simply trying `new File("/storage/emulated/0").isDirectory()`?

Comment: @wero Do you want me to try this? -  File file = new File(("/storage/emulated/0").isDirectory()); because this shows an error.

Comment: And yes I checked the value of file variable. The value that goes into that variable is correct.

Comment: Then simply make a tiny program which consists of `System.out.println(new File("/storage/emulated/0").isDirectory());`

Comment: But I checked the value of file using a toast.   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  and the value is correct. I need to know if there is any other way to check for a file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Android are you using? As far as I remember there are some restrictions in KitKat related to SD-Card Access. Maybe this will help at least a little:

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-bypass-Android-44-KitKat-external-SD-write-/

The restrictions are gone again in lollipop